# First Plant - Hydrangeas Dying

Tags: diagnosis, watering

Afternoon All,

I was recently gifted two hydrangeas and haven't really taken care of a potted plant before. I was hoping to get some help to make certain that I'm not killing these plants.

I transplanted them about two weeks ago in the DC area and have watered them a couple of times a week using a microspray system. I ran it until I saw water was coming out of the bottom of the pot. The flowers have started to lose their color and die and some of the leaves are getting brown spots. They get some morning sun on the front porch but are mostly in shade.

I don't know if this is just transplant shock or if I'm watering too much/too little/not watering correctly/ or if this is just normal. I'd really appreciate your feedback. Below is a photo of one of them and the same thing is happening with both.

Thank you so much for your help!

[image]

[image]